# How to make android studio highlight C code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I use Gradle experimental plugin for my ndk project. But it looks like Android Studio doesn't see all C functions like `memset()` or `fwrite()`. They are in red color (like in the screenshot below), and there is an error prompt when moving the cursor over it `Cannot resolve variable 'memset'` while project compiles without errors. All c++ code is highlighted perfectly. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

**UPD1:** also have found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203501), but it seems, that problem not only in ndk version.

**UPD2:** seems like the problem is in specified runtime. For now I use `stl "c++_static"`, if I switch it to `gnustl_static`, highlight works well.

Answer (score -1):

There are still limitations in `Android NDK`. Android Studio has not yet been updated to fully handle the experimental plugin so if your code runs, Then make sure typo and ignore the warnings and red lines.

As described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) developers had not added a simple way to create Android NDK projects till version 1.3 of Android studio. Instead, to explore the Android NDK support, either

1. *Follow the [Experimental Gradle Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) document which describes how to modify your project to use the current version of the experimental plugin, or*
2. *Check out some of the existing Android NDK samples which have been updated to work with the new Gradle plugin.*

After you completed that you can now build & run the project, and explore the various editing features: sample looks like

[image: sample]

Comment: Actually, I am already using Experimental Gradle Plugin and up-to-date version of android studio (2.1). Please, read my question more carefully, the problem occurs only with c code, for c++ it works well

Comment: Android Studio has not yet been updated to fully handle the experimental plugin so if your code runs, Then make sure typo but the warnings and red lines...

Comment: There are no typos if you take a look at my screenshot. `memset` is standard c function. This problem occurs with all c functions, like `fwrite`, `memcpy`, and even `FILE` structure. I doubt that there is c++ support in android studio and no c support.

Comment: No i didn't mean to say its mistake, But they won't be detected because NDK may not be fully implemented in android studio to detect all the methods. So I was suggesting you to be sure in typing such methods and ignore the warnings...